# Angularjs Dropdown OnChange Selected Text and Value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-options

I am new to `AngularJS` and trying to get Selected Text and Value from `Dropdown`. I followed a lot of tutorials with still unable to get there. `SelectedValue` and `SelectedText` are always `undefined`. Below is my code:

**Html:**

```
<div ng-app="SelectApp">
<div ng-controller="selectController">
    <select name="category-group" id="categoryGroup" class="form-control" ng-model="itemSelected" ng-change="onCategoryChange(itemSelected)">
        <option value="0">Select a category...</option>
        <option ng-repeat="category in categories" value="{{category.id}}"
             ng-disabled="category.disabled" ng-class="{'mainCategory' : category.disabled}">
             {{category.name}}
        </option>
     </select>
</div>
```

**Js:**

```
'use strict';
var app = angular.module('SelectApp', [ ]);
app.controller('selectController', ['$scope', '$window', function ($scope, $window) {

$scope.categories = [       
   { id: 1, name: "- Vehicles -", disabled: true },
   { id: 2, name: "Cars" },
   { id: 3, name: "Commercial vehicles", disabled: false },
   { id: 4, name: "Motorcycles", disabled: false },
   { id: 5, name: "Car & Motorcycle Equipment", disabled: false },
   { id: 6, name: "Boats", disabled: false },
   { id: 7, name: "Other Vehicles", disabled: false },
   { id: 8, name: "- House and Children -", disabled: true },
   { id: 9, name: "Appliances", disabled: false },
   { id: 10, name: "Inside", disabled: false },
   { id: 11, name: "Games and Clothing", disabled: false },
   { id: 12, name: "Garden", disabled: false }
];

$scope.onCategoryChange = function () {

    $window.alert("Selected Value: " + $scope.itemSelected.id + "\nSelected Text: " + $scope.itemSelected.name);

};
}]);
```

And one more thing, I have defined my first item as `Select a category...` then Why first item in Dropdown is always empty.

Below is my fiddle sample.
http://jsfiddle.net/Qgmz7/136/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That's because, your model `itemSelected` captures the current value of your select drop down which is nothing but the `value` attribute of your `option` element. You have

```
<option ng-repeat="category in categories" value="{{category.id}}">
```

in your code, so in the rendered version, you'll get

```
<option ng-repeat="category in categories" value="0">
```

but you're expecting `itemSelected` to be your category object and any attempt to query `id` or other property will return `undefined`.

You can use `ng-options` with `group by` with little bit of change to your data or you can use normal `ng-repeat`, get the selectedIndex and lookup the category object from your categories list using that index. Showcasing the first approach here.

**HTML**

```
<select name="category-group" id="categoryGroup" 
        ng-model="itemSelected" ng-change="onCategoryChange(itemSelected)" 
        ng-options="category.name group by category.group for category in categories">
</select>
```

**Updated Data**

```
$scope.categories = [
       { id: 0, name: "Select a category..."},
       { id: 1, name: "Cars", group : "- Vehicles -" },
       { id: 2, name: "Commercial vehicles", group : "- Vehicles -" },
       { id: 3, name: "Motorcycles", group : "- Vehicles -" }
 ];

 $scope.itemSelected = $scope.categories[0];
```

Instead of disabled property, you can add a `group` property which can be used in `group by`.

Here' an updated [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mLrynxh2/2/) to illustrate the idea.

Comment: This example will keep the group headers using `optgroup` in select element rendered by `group by` clause in `ng-options`. Hope this helps :)

Comment: that's good solution but why dropdown is empty for the first time.

Comment: That's because we've not set any default value for `itemSelected` in our controller. Add your default value to your categories list and set that value as shown [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mLrynxh2/2/)

Comment: Thanks a lot Ankantos. Very good solution and something new to learn. :)

Comment: Glad to be of help :)

Answer (score 8):

You should use `ng-options` to set object to your `ng-model` value on change of you select options.

**Markup**

```
<select name="category-group" id="categoryGroup" class="form-control" 
  ng-model="itemSelected" ng-change="onCategoryChange(itemSelected)" 
  ng-options="category.name for category in categories">
    <option value="0">Select a category...</option>
</select>
```

[**Fiddle Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/Qgmz7/137/)

**Update**

For persisting style you have to use `ng-repeat` there, in that case you will only have `id` binded to your `ng-model` and while retrieving whole object you need to filter your data.

```
$scope.onCategoryChange = function () {
    var currentSelected = $filter('filter')($scope.categories, {id: $scope.itemSelected})[0]
    $window.alert("Selected Value: " + currentSelected.id + "\nSelected Text: " + currentSelected.name);
};
```

[**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Qgmz7/138/)

Comment: It works but my css logic is gone. If you see my sample. - Vehicles - and - House and Children - are disabled and using different css.

Comment: @UsmanKhalid take a look at updated fiddle..which will work as you want

Comment: Thanks a lot. It is working fine but why dropdown is empty for the first time?

Answer (score 3):

```
<div ng-app="SelectApp">
    <div ng-controller="selectController">
    <select ng-change='onCategoryChange()' ng-model="itemSelected" ng-options="category.name for category in categories">
        <option value="">-- category --</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

//http://jsbin.com/zajipe/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 3):

A little change in your `onCategoryChange()` should work:

```
$scope.onCategoryChange = function () {
        $window.alert("Selected Value: " + $scope.categories[$scope.itemSelected - 1].id + "\nSelected Text: " + $scope.categories[$scope.itemSelected -1].name);

    };
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Qgmz7/144/

Comment: are you crazy to that..how come `$scope.categories[$scope.itemSelected]` will select a value from `categories`?

Comment: $scope.itemSelected Will return the value (as a Number) of the selected item in the option list. By passing it to the object You are able to select the n-property of the object and you will have access to the data.

Comment: could you please look at your fiddle it is showing wrong value as its considering index of an array

Comment: Updated the code. It should output the right values now.

Comment: No dude that could harm..if suppose you have skipped one/two element id and then took third one..then `$scope.itemSelected - 1` will won't work..

Answer (score 1):

`ngChange` only returns the value of your selected option and that's why you don't get the whole data.

Here's a working solution without changing your markup logic.

**Markup:**

```
<select
    name="category-group"
    id="categoryGroup"
    class="form-control"
    ng-model="id"     
    ng-change="onCategoryChange(id)">
```

**ngChange handler:**

```
 $scope.onCategoryChange = function (id) {
        //get selected item data from categories
        var selectedIndex = $scope.categories.map(function(obj) { return obj.id; }).indexOf( parseInt(id) );
        var itemSelected = $scope.categories[selectedIndex];

        $window.alert("Selected Value: " + itemSelected.id + "\nSelected Text: " + itemSelected.name);

    };
```

---

Another solution (little bit dirty) would be to change only the `value` of your options into something like this:

```
<option .... value="{{category.id}}|{{category.name}}">
```

...and inside your actual ngChange handler, just split the value to get all the values as an array:

```
$scope.onCategoryChange = function (itemSelected) {
    $scope.itemSelected = itemSelected.split('|'); //string value to array
    $window.alert("Selected Value: " + $scope.itemSelected[0] + "\nSelected Text: " + $scope.itemSelected[1]);

};
```

Answer (score 0):

Here very Simple and easy code What I did

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
Select Person: 
<select ng-model="selectedData">
   <option ng-repeat="person in persons" value={{person.age}}>
         {{person.name}}
   </option>
</select>
<div ng-bind="selectedData">AGE:</DIV>
<br>
</div>


    <script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('myCtrl',myCtrlFn);
    function myCtrlFn($scope) {

    $scope.persons =[
        {'name': 'Prabu','age': 20},
        {'name': 'Ram','age': 24},
        {'name': 'S','age': 14},
        {'name': 'P','age': 15}
        ];
    }
    </script>
```